# How can I view the parameters passed to a native function in the core dump of a .NET process?

Tags: windbg

I have a full memory dump of a .NET process. There is one thread which I would like to examine. Specifically, I want to know for how long it was asked to wait.

Here is !ClrStack:

```
0:049> !CLRStack
OS Thread Id: 0x1170 (49)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
000000002139e308 0000000076f7e18a [HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 000000002139e308] System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, UInt32, Boolean, Boolean)
000000002139e430 000007fef7d43264 System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, Int64, Boolean, Boolean)
000000002139e470 000007fef85e4407 System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(System.TimeSpan, Boolean)
000000002139e4b0 000007fe9b66b0a4 BJE.CriticalThreadManager.Pause(BJE.ICriticalThread, BJE.CriticalThreadImportance, System.Threading.WaitHandle) [d:\tfs\RTQA150520\SharpTop\BJE\BJE\ICriticalThread.cs @ 297]
000000002139e540 000007fe9b66a600 BJE.CriticalThreadManager.CriticalThreadMain(BJE.ICriticalThread, BJE.CriticalThreadOptionsAttribute, System.Threading.AutoResetEvent) [d:\tfs\RTQA150520\SharpTop\BJE\BJE\ICriticalThread.cs @ 238]
000000002139e610 000007fef7d239a5 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
000000002139e770 000007fef7d23719 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
000000002139e7a0 000007fef7d236f7 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
000000002139e7f0 000007fef7d3adc1 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
000000002139eb08 000007fef8f1a7f3 [GCFrame: 000000002139eb08] 
000000002139ee58 000007fef8f1a7f3 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 000000002139ee58]
```

So, I know the thread is waiting. The problem is that `!CLRStack -a` does not tell me the parameters of the wait:

```
0:049> !CLRStack -a
OS Thread Id: 0x1170 (49)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
000000002139e308 0000000076f7e18a [HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 000000002139e308] System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, UInt32, Boolean, Boolean)
000000002139e430 000007fef7d43264 System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, Int64, Boolean, Boolean)
    PARAMETERS:
        waitableSafeHandle = <no data>
        millisecondsTimeout = <no data>
        hasThreadAffinity = <no data>
        exitContext = <no data>
    LOCALS:
        <no data>

000000002139e470 000007fef85e4407 System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(System.TimeSpan, Boolean)
    PARAMETERS:
        this = <no data>
        timeout = <no data>
        exitContext = <no data>
    LOCALS:
        <CLR reg> = 0x0000000000000000

...
```

I can view the native stack trace:

```
0:049> kb
RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
000007fe`fcd21430 : ffffffff`fffffffe 000007fe`f8f15a1f 48d34863`a6a8cbd7 00000000`80114f80 : ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xa
00000000`76d31753 : 00000000`2139dfc8 00000000`2139dfc0 00000000`00000000 00000003`8d0d45d0 : KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xe8
000007fe`f9038976 : 00000000`0001d4c0 00000000`2139e270 00000000`2139e308 00000000`2139e129 : kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation+0xb3
000007fe`f903877a : 00000000`00000001 00000000`0001d4c0 00000003`5ed4e343 00000000`00000001 : clr!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx_SO_TOLERANT+0x62
000007fe`f9038591 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x1d0
000007fe`f9048411 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x7d
000007fe`f7d43264 : 01d17a4c`8431cbd7 00000000`0001d4c0 00000000`80122700 000007fe`9b66b700 : clr!WaitHandleNative::CorWaitOneNative+0x175
000007fe`f85e4407 : 00000000`80114f80 000007fe`9b66b729 00000000`801224e8 00000004`0015e7e8 : mscorlib_ni+0x4c3264
000007fe`9b66b0a4 : 00000000`80114f80 00000000`47868c00 00000000`801224e8 00000000`80114f80 : mscorlib_ni+0xd64407
000007fe`9b66a600 : 00000000`805ba018 00000000`803e8558 00000000`00000001 00000000`805c3b88 : 0x000007fe`9b66b0a4
000007fe`f7d239a5 : 00000000`801224e8 00000000`80114f80 00000000`80122758 00000000`80122708 : 0x000007fe`9b66a600
000007fe`f7d23719 : 00000000`000a0008 00000000`770426d0 0044005c`003a0064 006f0066`00790061 : mscorlib_ni+0x4a39a5
000007fe`f7d236f7 : 00000003`8023bdf0 00380043`00460054 00540045`004e0030 006c006c`0064002e : mscorlib_ni+0x4a3719
000007fe`f7d3adc1 : 00000000`805c4058 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x4a36f7
000007fe`f8f1a7f3 : 00000000`805c4080 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x4badc1
000007fe`f8f1a6de : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
000007fe`f8f1ae76 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000004 00000000`2139eb08 00000000`2139ebc8 : clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4a
000007fe`f90c969d : 00000000`2139ef80 00000000`2139eec0 000007fe`f7f6bf38 00000000`176cb400 : clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x251
000007fe`f8f1c121 : 00000000`805c4080 00000000`2139eec0 00000000`176cb400 000007fe`f8e35f08 : clr!ThreadNative::KickOffThread_Worker+0x105
000007fe`f8f1c0a8 : 00000000`2139eec0 000007fe`f8f12ba4 00000000`2139edd0 000007fe`f8f13a6a : clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+0x2d
000007fe`f8f1c019 : 00000000`00000001 006f0066`00000001 005c0065`00630072 005c0045`004a0042 : clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+0x6c
000007fe`f8f1c15f : ffffffff`ffffffff 00000000`176cb400 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+0x75
000007fe`f90c957e : 00000000`176cb400 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000008 : clr!ManagedThreadBase_FullTransitionWithAD+0x2f
000007fe`f905fcb6 : 00000000`0caef010 00000000`176cb400 00000000`2139ef58 00000000`00000000 : clr!ThreadNative::KickOffThread+0xd2
00000000`76d259cd : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x7d
00000000`76f5b891 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
```

[KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) seems to be a well known function with the following signature:

```
DWORD WINAPI WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(
  _In_       DWORD  nCount,
  _In_ const HANDLE *lpHandles,
  _In_       BOOL   bWaitAll,
  _In_       DWORD  dwMilliseconds,
  _In_       BOOL   bAlertable
);
```

However, I am having a hard time to map the output of `kb` for that function onto its expected parameters.

Indeed, `kb` claims the following parameters are passed to that function:

```
00000000`2139dfc8 00000000`2139dfc0 00000000`00000000 00000003`8d0d45d0
```

They do not make much sense to me given the method signature, but it is obvious to me that I misunderstand something.

How do I figure out the parameter values here?

**EDIT**

```
0:049> kn 3
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
01 00000000`2139de90 00000000`76d31753 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xe8
02 00000000`2139df90 000007fe`f9038976 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation+0xb3
03 00000000`2139e020 000007fe`f903877a clr!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx_SO_TOLERANT+0x62
0:049> .frame /c /r 1
01 00000000`2139de90 00000000`76d31753 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xe8
rax=00000008b7f8fd38 rbx=000000002139dfc0 rcx=0000000000601eb0
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000001 rdi=0000000000000001
rip=000007fefcd21430 rsp=000000002139de90 rbp=0000000000000001
 r8=00000004c4990798  r9=00000000176cb400 r10=000007fe997ce068
r11=0000000300f58448 r12=000000002139ded8 r13=000000002139df30
r14=0000000000000001 r15=0000000000000001
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xe8:
000007fe`fcd21430 8bd8            mov     ebx,eax
```

Comment: Run !sos.dso or !sosex.mdso and look for WaitHandle/SafeWaitHandle and similar types of objects on the stack.  This is what you have to do when debugging optimized code because the variable information is not tracked by the jitter.

Comment: But what about `KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` ? Its parameters are supposed to be on the stack or in the registers. Is there a way to access them when analyzing the core dump?

Comment: Those adresses you see mean little in x64 calling conventions. In x86, these are the values that get passed to the function but not so in x64. *"the first four function arguments are not saved on the stack typically but just passed in registers"*. I would give [cmkd](http://yacoder.net/blog/2013/12/24/using-cmkd-to-find-function-arguments-in-x64-dumps/?doing_wp_cron=1457677852.3503689765930175781250) a try in trying to figure out the parameters passed in an automated way. That said, the current register values should contain at least the handle the thread is waiting on

Comment: `kb` in x64 is seriously broken. WinDbg should at least give a big warning in that case. It happened to me very often already and is one of the most frequent problems when I'm asked for help.

Comment: This may work: Use `.frame /c /r 1` to set and view the local context of KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx (use `kn` to make sure it's frame 1). Register R9 will hopefully have the value for dwMilliseconds. You could sanity check by seeing if RCX (nCount) is reasonable (an integer less than 65) and also by passing the first handle in lpHandles (RDX) to !handle like so I think `!handle poi(RDX) f`. If you get good output from !handle and RCX is less than 65, chances are R9 is in fact dwMilliseconds.

Comment: The process got completely hung, which could be explained by extremely high dwMilliseconds value (assuming R9 is it). How did it get there, that is another question.

Comment: @mark, the parameters could be anywhere.  Such is the joy of debugging optimized code.  With !sos.dso and !sosex.mdso, you get an opportunity to find them.  You just have to take the output of the command and take your knowledge of the code to make your best guess, which is usually not difficult because you generally see the only plausible parameter values sticking out.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. Cannot say I am more cheerful now than before, though.